# Can't call function on HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm starting to write jQuery in Vanilla JS and my selectors work but when I call my append function on the HTML element I get an "is not a function" error.

```
var $ = function(){
    this.select = function(input) {
        if (input.split("")[0] == "#") {
            input = input.slice(1, input.length)
            return document.getElementById(input)

        }
        else if (input.split("")[0] == ".") {
            input = input.slice(1, input.length)
            return document.getElementsByClassName(input)

        }
        else {
            return document.getElementsByTagName(input)

        }
    },

    this.append = function(text) {
     return this.innerhtml = this.innerhtml + text

}
};
```

my console attempts:

```
var myQuery = new $();
```

returns undefined

```
myQuery.select("#testspan")
```

returns my `span` tag here

```
myQuery.select("#testspan").append("hellohello")
```

returns error

> VM2207:1 Uncaught TypeError: myQuery.select(...).append is not a function(…)

Comment: If you want to chain your functions they need to return either `this` (to return the current instance) or create a new instance with `new $()` and return that. Currently your `select()` method returns an object that is either a single DOM element or a list of DOM elements, neither of which has an `.append()` method.

Comment: You may also want to replace the whole `select` function with `querySelectorAll` :) You don't need to parse selector yourself.

Comment: @nnnnnn It should be an (accepted) answer, I guess.

Comment: As an aside, `input.split("")[0]` is a weird way to get the first character of a string. Try `input.charAt(0)` or `input[0]` instead.

Comment: appendChild https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: You can even use startsWith("#") as you can see in my example below

Comment: What does "jQuery in Vanilla JS" mean? The very definition of the unfortunate term "vanilla JS" is that it does **not** use jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your snippet the return of each of the `select` method return a DOM element (or collection). Really what you would like to do is called `Chaining` where the result of the method returns the original object. Therefore you can keep calling additional methods on the same object.

Now in your example you are going to need a collection of elements (`nodes`) somewhere the object can then access again. Here is a simple example.

```
var $ = function () {
    this.nodes = [];
    this.select = function (input) {
        var self = this;
        if (input.split("")[0] == "#") {
            input = input.slice(1, input.length)
            var node = document.getElementById(input);
            if (node)
                this.nodes.push(node);

        }
        else if (input.split("")[0] == ".") {
            input = input.slice(1, input.length)
            Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName(input), 0).forEach(function (node) {
                self.nodes.push(node);
            });
        }
        else {
            Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName(input), 0).forEach(function (node) {
                self.nodes.push(node);
            });
        }
        return this;
    },

    this.append = function (text) {
        this.nodes.forEach(function (i) {
            i.innerHTML += text;
        });
        return this;
    }
};
```

Sample Html:

```
<p id="test">This is test </p>
<p>This is number to</p>
```

Console (Chrome):

```
$ = new $()
$ {nodes: Array[0]}
$.select('p').append('hi')
```

Now a little issue here is you are (in the console) setting `$ = new $()` which effectivly overwrites the ability to call `new $()` again in the same script. I have provided a fiddle below that renames this to `myQuery`. Also changed that every time you call select will clear the `node` array.

Revised:

```
var myQuery = function () {
    this.nodes = [];
    this.select = function (input) {
        this.nodes = [];
        var self = this;
        if (input.split("")[0] == "#") {
            input = input.slice(1, input.length)
            var node = document.getElementById(input);
            if (node)
                this.nodes.push(node);

        }
        else if (input.split("")[0] == ".") {
            input = input.slice(1, input.length)
            Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName(input), 0).forEach(function (node) {
                self.nodes.push(node);
            });
        }
        else {
            Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName(input), 0).forEach(function (node) {
                self.nodes.push(node);
            });
        }
        return this;
    },

    this.append = function (text) {
        this.nodes.forEach(function (i) {
            i.innerHTML += text;
        });
        return this;
    }
};


$ = new myQuery();
$.select('p').append(' test selection by tag name ');

$ = new myQuery();
$.select('.p1').append(' test selection by class ');

$ = new myQuery();
$.select('#p1').append(' test selection by id ');

$ = new myQuery();
$.select('#p2').append(' test selection by id ').append('and then chanined').select('.p2').append(' still chaining');
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kxwt9gmg/

Answer (score 1):

You need to change up your approach a bit.  You are wanting to *store* a result and call a method on it.  You can ONLY call a method that that particular object has.  That object you are returning, the raw html element, doesn't have that method.  What you want to do is store the html element and then return an OBJECT that performs operations on what was stored.  You can accomplish this using closure. For example:

```
function miniQuery(input){

  function elementIterate(collection, action){
    for (var i = elements.length -1; i >= 0; i-- ){
      collection[i].style.display = action;
    }
  }

  var isCollection = function(element){
    if(element instanceof HTMLCollection){
      return true
    } else{
      return false
    }
  }

  function findElement(element){
    if (element.startsWith("#")) {
    // id element selector
    return document.getElementById(element.substring(1));
  } else if (element.startsWith(".")) {
    // class element selector
    return document.getElementsByClassName(element.substring(1));
  } else {
    // tag element selector
    return document.getElementsByTagName(element);
  };
}
if (input != undefined) {
  var _this = this;
  this.element = findElement(input);
  var elements = findElement(input);
}
return {

  append: function(content, position = 'beforeend'){
    var elements = _this.element;
    if (isCollection(elements)) {
      for(var i = elements.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
        elements[i].insertAdjacentHTML(position, content)
      }
    }else{
      elements.insertAdjacentHTML(position, content);
    }
  }

  }
}

function $(input){
  return selector(input);
}



function selector(input){
  var query = new miniQuery(input);
  return query;
}
```